# $\log_6(x)= \log_6(x-1)-\log_6(2)$ Solve for X

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

$\log_6(x)= \log_6(x-1)-\log_6(2)$  I have to solve for x.  Is $\log(a) = \log(b)$ a logarithm rule?  I was wondering why the equation can only have 1 log on one side of the equal sign and one log on the other side?

This method works $$\log_6(x)=\log_6\bigg(\frac{x+1}{2}\bigg)$$

The next steps are are easy just solve $$x = \bigg(\frac{x+1}{2}\bigg)$$ $$2x=x+1$$ $$x=1$$

I understand when subtracting logs with the same base the log can be simplified into a quotient or when adding two logs the logs can be simplified into a product.  I guess that is a good thing.  The log rules are different than algebra and may be this is just the standard order of treating logs with the same base.

I was following this hyper link while studying and was looking to see why an equation has to  be stated as log(a) = log(b) before x can be solved for?  [Help with logarithms website](http://www.sosmath.com/algebra/logs/log4/log47/log4715/log4715.html)

Comment: In the original equation, you wrote $\log_6(x - 1)$.  You later changed it to $\log_6(x + 1)$.  Check your work.

Comment: In the title, there's an equation in $x$, which we are asked to solve for $X$. This is impossible to do, unless we are given some relation between $x$ and $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Demand $x>0$ and $x>1$,then rewrite the Eq.
$$\log_6 x=\log_6 \frac{(x-1)}{2}
\implies 2x-(x-1)=0 \implies x=-1.$$
So no solution as it contradicts the demand.

Answer (score 1):

since the logarithm function is an injection we have log a = log b and we have log a - log b = log a/b
therefore:
$$\log_6 x = \log_6 (x-1) - \log_6(2) = \log_6(\frac{x-1}{2}) \Rightarrow x = \frac{x-1}{2} \Rightarrow x = -1 $$
but since the domain of the logarithm is $\mathbb{R}^+$ there are no solutions.